# Why is there no Apparmor profile for the terminal?

Tags: apparmor

I understand that Apparmor profiles are useful for securing programs that have access to the internet. Hence the question. I don't see any "terminal"-related profile [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~apparmor-dev/apparmor-profiles/master/files/head:/ubuntu/12.10/).

Comment: You said terminal , I ask something else : Where is the profile for skype ? This is a profile that is definitely necessary,  for such application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal doesn't need a profile. By default, terminal doesn't do anything. Bash (by default) is the command that lets you access a shell (horridly worded, but accurate enough for this answer). From there, you can run other programs. So any profile against terminal would be totally useless (as it doesn't access anything other then it's preference files).

Keep in mind that AppArmor is basically a supplement to already existing security. If you never want terminal to access a file you can create your own profile and set it up.

As you can see in `cat /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump` tcpdump (a command that you would run from bash, inside a terminal) has a profile. This is how you would "secure" commands.

Also, in `cat /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/bash` you will see that bash has a profile. Thus "terminal" is protected.